# Calendar events attached to email with java

Tags: java, email, outlook, calendar, gmail

I've to create events on calendar using Java and I have two problem:

1. The events is correcly viewed on smartphone and outlook, but on gmail from pc no events appear
2. The timezone: how should I manage the time? I may have events in all the world, what time I have set for the events(UTC or the correct events date)?

This is the code for email:

```
private void sendSimpleMessage(Mail mail) throws com.exception.MailException {
        try {
             JavaMailSender mailSender = mailConfig.getMailSender();
             MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.getFrom(), ""));
            message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(mail.getTo()));

         // Create an alternative Multipart
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

            String mailContent = getContentFromTemplate(mail.getTemplate(),mail.getModel());

            BodyPart descriptionPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            descriptionPart.setContent(mailContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            multipart.addBodyPart(descriptionPart);

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
            String iCalContent = getContentFromTemplate(TEMPLATE_CALENDAR_RESERVATION,mail.getModel());

            messageBodyPart.setContent(iCalContent, "text/calendar;method=CANCEL");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            mailSender.send(message);

        } catch (Throwable exception) {
            throw new com.exception.MailException(exception);
        }
    }
```

this is the event configuration (TEMPLATE_CALENDAR_RESERVATION):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:${to}
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:${from}
DTSTART:${starDateString}
DTEND:${endDateString}
LOCATION:${room}
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SEQUENCE:0
UID:${starDateString}${endDateString}${nowDateString}${from}${to}
DTSTAMP:${nowDateString}
CATEGORIES:Meeting
DESCRIPTION:${subject}
SUMMARY:${subject}
PRIORITY:${priority}
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks

Comment: Pew tricky: Maybe check the gmail policys, maybe something is missing in your email. For the timezone: If you have event all over the world I would use the timezone where the event is located and add the date time group (like UTC, etc.). That would be the most work in terms of programming but would definitely look pretty fancy.

Comment: when I set the timezone of the event, outlook add its timezone (example if event is utc+2 outlook create event with UTC+4)

Comment: Ah that´s what you meant. Missunderstood you there. Then I would just use the timezone of the creator. Outlook should transform that time automatically if it´s properly set up. Or you could write the local time for the event into some kind of additional information field

Comment: Outlook add timezone, but gmail not so I can't manage timezone of my reservations